# ¿Cómo comparar los campos de dos tablas en distintas bases de datos en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He encontrado mucha información sobre este tema que coinciden en parte con lo que quiero, pero me han terminado por confundir.

Verán tengo en una base de datos (BD1) una tabla, digamos que se llama `tablaOrigen`  y en una BD2 una `tablaResumen`, en esta última tabla solo se ha extraido registros de un intervalo de fecha determinado (ejemplo: 2009 al 2012), pero ya pasó un buen tiempo, me están pidiendo que compare todos los registros de la `tablaResumen`(en todos sus campos, que son mas de 60) con los de su origen en `tablaOrigen`. Quisera que me arroje las filas que cambiaron en alguno de sus campos y algo que me ayude a identificar los campos que originaron la modificación de las filas. Lo único que acabo de comprobar es que el numero de registros según la fecha coinciden en ambas tablas.

Una vez determinada las filas distintas o las que no se encuentran en la tabla "Resumen" mediante un `EXCEPT` (Primer proceso), y con un segundo procedimiento sobre este resultado para identificar los campos modificados, la respuesta que espero es mas o menos la siguiente:

**Resultado con los campos identificados y que originaron los cambios en las filas:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es que es posible claro, solo poner los campos que se modificaron y los demás rellenarlos con un null.

O simplemente poner las columnas involucradas en las modificaciones de los campos como en el siguiente dibujo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque esto lo veo un poco más engorroso. No se me ocurre otra forma de mostrarles los campos modificados. Aunque ya me resigné a tener que copiar en el script las más de 60 columnas, creo que no hay otra forma.

Comment: Hay algún índice en `tablaOrigen`?, sólo necesitas comparar cantidad de filas en el período de tiempo?, no que sean los mismos datos?. `la tabla Resumen es 5 veces más grande que su Resumen`, qué significa esto?. Las bases de datos están en el mismo servidor?

Comment: Están en el mismo servidor las BD's, no hay índices, ni PK's, solo el código que identifica a cada registro, el de 5 veces más grandes solo era una acotación algo redundante tal vez, para dar entender que la tablaOrigen es mayor que la tablaResumen. Lo que quiero es saber si los registros coinciden en todos sus campos (más de 60). Registros que en sus momento se extrajo mediante una clausula de tablaOrigen -- a --> TablaResumen.

Comment: Más o menos cuántas filas hay en cada tabla?. Ok, entonces hay una columna (`código`) que los une

Comment: SI claro, tablaResumen es una parte de tablaOrigen (es una extracción, más no están relacionadas), pero con el tiempo pudo haber algún cambio en uno de sus campos de tablaOrigen, son más de 80 millones de registros en "Resumen" y mas de 200 millones en "Origen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con la siguiente consulta puedes ver la diferencia que ambas tablan tendrían:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tablaOrigen o
FULL JOIN dbo.tablaResumen r
    ON o.codigo = r.codigo
WHERE o.fecha BETWEEN '20090101' AND '20121231'
AND (r.codigo IS NULL or o.codigo IS NULL);
```

Esto te entregará los resultados de datos que están en la tablaOrigen y no en tablaResumen para el período de tiempo que comentaste o viceversa.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Según tu comentario, lo que necesitas es comparar todas las columnas de ambas tablas, para saber si han cambiado en el tiempo. Para esto, lo más sencillo es usar `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM BaseDatos1.dbo.tablaOrigen o
WHERE o.fecha BETWEEN '20090101' AND '20121231'
EXCEPT 
SELECT *
FROM BaseDatos2.dbo.tablaResumen r;
```

Esto asume que ambas tablas tienen exactamente la misma estructura de columnas. Si no fuera así, debes listar las columnas que quieres comparar:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ....., col60
FROM dbo.tablaOrigen o
WHERE o.fecha BETWEEN '20090101' AND '20121231'
EXCEPT 
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ....., col60
FROM dbo.tablaResumen r;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Ok, según tu nuevo requerimiento, lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(o.codigo,r.codigo) codigo,
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(r.col1,'') <> ISNULL(o.col1,'') THEN r.col1
        END col1,
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(r.col2,'') <> ISNULL(o.col2,'') THEN r.col2
        END col2,
        ........ -- repetir para cada columna de tu tabla
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(r.col60,'') <> ISNULL(o.col60,'') THEN r.col60
        END col60
FROM dbo.tablaOrigen o
FULL JOIN dbo.tablaResumen r
    ON o.codigo = r.codigo
WHERE o.fecha BETWEEN '20090101' AND '20121231'
AND (   r.codigo IS NULL 
        OR o.codigo IS NULL
        OR ISNULL(r.col1,'') <> ISNULL(o.col1,'') -- acá depende del tipo de datos de la columna
        OR ISNULL(r.col2,'') <> ISNULL(o.col2,'') 
        OR .........    -- repetir para cada columna de tu tabla
        OR ISNULL(r.col60,'') <> ISNULL(o.col60,''));
```

Comment: gracias por responder, me sale un error en la ejecución, me imagino por que no se le ha especificado a que tabla pertenecen los campos seleccionados, ya que dichas tablas son idénticas en estructura, aprovechando el comentario, la última línea  del código que pusiste no la entendí. Sé que aún no las he ejecutado ¿pero en caso haya discordancia en algún campo de las filas seleccionadas como me daría cuenta?

Comment: @Fran.J necesitaría ver exactamente el código que usaste y el mensaje de error, ya que tal como está escrito no debería entregar error alguno

Comment: Disculpa, fue un error mío, me olvidé especificarle la base de datos de una de ellas ya que están en diferentes BD's. Te preguntaba sobre la interpretación de los resultados, como me daría cuenta si algún campo ha sido modificado, y sobre la última línea de tu código.

Comment: @Fran.J En este primer caso, no estamos viendo diferencia entre las columnas, sino que simplemente si existen los mismos valores para código o no. Para comparar el resto de las columnas habría que hacer algo diferente. Es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: Si, en realidad necesito eso, digamos que se extrajeron 80 millones de registros de una TablaOrigen a una "Resumen" en otra BDResumen (No están relacionadas obviamente). Lo que quiero comprobar es que si algún campo (son más de 60) de estos registros en "Origen" ha cambiado en el tiempo (Esta es la tabla que para en constante actualización) con respecto a  sus "copias" en "Resumen". Sospecho y me temo que se tenga que poner todos los campos en el script, espero que no.

Comment: @Fran.J ok, actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Entiendo que el `EXCEPT` hace una diferencia, de haber un cambio en algún campo de algunas de las filas (en Origen), estos registros se listarán en el resultado ¿verdad? Pero como darme cuenta que campo es el que ha cambiado teniendo en cuenta que son más de 60. 

Psdt: ¿Puedo poner asterisco (*) en vez de poner todas las columnas?

Comment: @Fran.J la verdad es que esta pregunta cada vez va creciendo con más detalles. Para saber cuál valor es diferente, en este caso tendrás que ver todas las columnas, no hay ningún metodo sencillo para encontrar exactamente la diferencia en alguna columna particular, a menos que escribas 60 veces cada consulta (algo que puedes hacer). Como dice mi respuesta, sí puedes usar `*` en caso que ambas tablas tengan **exactamente** la misma estructura de columnas

Comment: En realidad es lo que siempre quise hallar, ¿Podrías ayudarme con un ejemplo suponiendo que las tablas tengan 2 o 3 columnas?, yo me encargo de llenar las 60 columnas me imagino.

Comment: @Fran.J Si es lo que siempre quisiste encontrar, entonces sería bueno que escribieras en tu pregunta un ejemplo de datos de la tabla de origen, otros de la tabla resumen, y qué resultado exactamente te gustaría obtener. Así evito volver a escribir una respuesta que tendré que modificar nuevamente

Comment: Ok, pero no soy muy bueno en esto, recién estoy comenzando, si tú me muestras los códigos asumiré que va de acorde a mi pregunta principal (de la 6ta a la 7ma línea), y no te diré que no es lo que quiero hasta el momento de ejecutarla.

Comment: @Fran.J `Quisera que me arroje las filas que cambiaron en alguno de sus campos, o algo que me ayude a identificarlos`, esto lo hace el `EXCEPT`, lo que quieres ahora además es que te diga cuál columna en particular es la que cambió. Lo más sencillo, como te comenté, es que escribas un resultado de ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Ya modifiqué mi pregunta graficando lo que quisiera como respuesta.

Comment: @Fran.J ok, actualicé mi respuesta. Espero que no haya nuevos requerimientos

Comment: Gracias por seguir el tema Lamak esto si me sirve.