# Como comparar dos tablas de bases distintas y que de resultado los campos que no coincidan. PL SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, data, migration

Necesito hacer una migracion de datos y quiero comparar numeros telefonicos de una tabla de una base con la tabla de otra base que me de como resultado los numeros que no se repiten.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías formular mejor tu pregunta? ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Tienes algún código que hayas probado? Te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo formular una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Verifica esta pregunta que ya fue respondida a ver si se ata a tu necesidad. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48040/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-los-campos-de-dos-tablas-en-distintas-bases-de-datos-en-sql-serve

Answer (score -1):

A través de un `LEFT JOIN` puedes comparar el campo de una tabla con el campo de otra tabla y estableces el condicional `WHERE` para hallar los registros que no coincidan.

A continuación el código:

```
SELECT tabla1.campo1 as campo1
FROM tabla1 LEFT JOIN tabla2 ON tabla2.campo1=tabla1.campo1
WHERE tabla_2.campo1 IS NULL
```